# AngularJS directive controller's scope accessible from outside directive, why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Came across something interesting while experimenting. For some reason I am able to access the scope of a controller specified inside a directive declaration from outside the directive.

Here is the sample code:

```
myApp.directive('lockToggle', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem) {
            elem.bind('click', function (e) {
                scope.locked = !scope.locked;
                scope.$apply();
            });
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.locked = false;
            $scope.hello = function () {
                alert('hello');
            };
        }
    };
});
```

and here is my markup:

```
<button lock-toggle>
  Toggle Lock
</button>
<button ng-disabled="locked" ng-click="hello()">
  Click Me!
</button>
```

When I click on the button `Toggle Lock`, the `Click Me!` button disables and enables correctly. And, when I click the `Click Me!` button, the method `hello()` on the controllers scope is called.

My question is why? Shouldn't the scope of the controller declared in the directive be isolated to the directives scope in the html? I would expect it to behave in the same way as other controllers, e.g.:

```
<!--Can't access the scope of MyController-->

<div ng-controller="MyController">
  .    
  .
  <!--CAN access the scope of MyController-->
  .
  .
</div>

<!--Can't access the scope of MyController-->
```

But for some reason, this doesn't seem to apply to my earlier example above. Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can decide how your directive scope should behave and if it shall inherit from the parent scope:

```
myApp.directive('lockToggle', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {}, // Will create an isolated scope
    link: function (scope, elem) {
        elem.bind('click', function (e) {
            scope.locked = !scope.locked;
            scope.$apply();
        });
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {
        $scope.locked = false;
        $scope.hello = function () {
            alert('hello');
        };
    }
  };
});
```

Currently, you do not specify a `scope` attribute, which is equal to `scope:false`. Therefore, the directive does not create a scope.

**Further information**

- [A very neat lecture on directives](http://blog.ponyfoo.com/2014/02/19/angle-brackets-synergistic-directives)
- [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile)

Comment: Ah ok, so, in my example above, is my parent scope the `$rootScope`? Or, how does inheriting from the parent scope allow me to access newly added properties outside of that inherited scope? I would expect the inheritance process to produce a copy of the parent scope, with prototype linking, rather than modifying the parent scope itself (which seems to be the case above) and not the copy.

Comment: In your example, the directives scope is equal to the scope that handles the rest of that markup section. It is not the $rootScope but a child of it. If you want to add properties to the directives scope that are not directly visible to the parent, create an isolated scope (`scope:{}`) or tell the directive to create a new child scope: `scope:true`.

Comment: I want to add that I was quite confused about this topic for a while, too. The first link that I have provided has helped me to finally understand the concept :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is accessible is that you are adding it to same scope shared by your parent controller:

```
controller: function ($scope) {
    $scope.locked = false;
    $scope.hello = function () {
        alert('hello');
    };
}
```

Here $scope is of your parent controller and since in JavaScript object is by reference so you adding it to your parent controller.

If you want to initialize variable only for directive scope then use scope:

```
scope:{
  //properties
}
```